# how to make a file unreadable without corrupting

Tags: batch-file

I am currently a computer science student, and am trying to teach myself how to lock a folder with a password.  I have the lock working, but the problem is that the file is still readable.  Anyone can open the file in edit and see pass=="PASSWORD", is there anyway that i am able to make the file unreadable as well as uneditable?  Thank you!

Comment: Pick a different programming language.

Comment: The word you are searching for is __encryption__. Encrypting a folder or file is built-in in NTFS. Open the properties of the file or folder, click on button Advanced and enable encryption for the file/folder. See for example [How secure is NTFS encryption?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8307/) There are also a lot of encryption tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it all you need to do is convert the readable text file into something called binary file or byte code file which other person can't read without processing it into the software or application you can do that trick.

Comment: While you are correct, your answer would be significantly improved if you included code for how to achieve this.